# How to combine a row of cells in VBA if certain column values are the same

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database where all of the input from the user (through a userform) gets stored. In the database, each column is a different category for the type of data (ex. date, shift, quantity, etc) and the data from the userform input gets put into its corresponding category. For some of the data, all the data is the same except for the quantity. I was wondering how I could combine these rows into one and add the quantities to each other for the whole database (ex. combining the first and third data entries). I have tried playing around with a couple different loops but can't seem to figure anything out.

```
Period    Date    Line    Shift   Type    Quantity   

4 x 2     4/3/18   A       3       14       18  
4 x 2     4/3/18   A       3       13       12  
4 x 2     4/3/18   A       3       14       15
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! If you could share the code you've tried already, it would make it easier for us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: What kind of database?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to modify the underlying database, you might be able to query the data into the format you want by including all the other columns in a GROUP BY statement, save the result to another table, then replace the original table with the properly formatted one.

If you have the data in Excel and you just want to view it with the duplicate rows summed, a Pivot Table would be a good choice. You can select all the other columns as rows for the Pivot Table and sum of Quantity as the values.